# Proving that $||v^T||_2=||v||_2$ for $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: matrix-calculus, matrix-norms

I'm trying to prove that $\|v^T\|_2=\|v\|_2$ for $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$. The first norm is the matrix norm, and the second norm is the usual euclidian norm.

I already prove that:

- $\|v\|_2\leq \|v\|_1\leq \sqrt{n} \|v\|_2;$
- $\|v\|_\infty\leq \|v\|_2\leq \sqrt{n} \|v\|_\infty; $
- $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\|v\|_\infty\leq \|v\|_1\leq \sqrt{n} \|v\|_\infty;$

and, for matrix norms, if $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$:

- $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\|A\|_\infty\leq \|A\|_2\leq \sqrt{m} \|A\|_\infty;$
- $\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\|A\|_1\leq \|A\|_2\leq \sqrt{n} \|A\|_1.$

Finally, I also proved that

- $\|v^T\|_1=\|v\|_\infty$;
- $\|v^T\|_\infty=\|v^T\|_1$.

With all these relations I managed to prove that

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\|v\|_2\leq \|v^T\|_2\leq \sqrt{n}\|v\|_2,
$$
and I don't know how to "remove" these $\sqrt{n}$ and prove the equality.

Comment: FYI - `$\|v\|$` gives a much nicer norm than `$||v||$`: $\|v\|$ vs $||v||$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that by Matrix norm you mean
$$\tag{1}
\|v^\top\|_2=\sup_{w\not=0}\frac{v\cdot w}{\|w\|_2}\,.
$$
The [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) says
$$
|v\cdot w|\le \|v\|_2\,\|w\|_2
$$
with equality holding if and only if $v$ and $w$ are linearly dependent. This means that the sup on the RHS of (1) is smaller than $\|v\|_2$ and is attained for $w=v$.
It follows that
$$\tag{2}
\|v^\top\|_2=\frac{v\cdot v}{\|v\|_2}=\|v\|_2\,.
$$